# C++ equivalent of C# object keyword

Tags: c++

What is the C++ equivalent of C# object type?

I want to do the C++ equivalent of this:

```
public enum TokenType {
    Number,
    Operator,
}

public class Token
{
   TokenType type;
   object value;
   public Token(TokenType type, object value)
   {
       switch (type)
       {
           case TokenType.Number:
                break;
           case TokenType.Operator:
               break;
           default:
                // throw some error
                break;
       }
       this.type = type;
       this.value = value;
   }
}
```

I cannot use a template argument for the class because I do not know if the input is going to be a `char`, `double` or `string`, and I need to declare a `Token` before knowing.

Comment: You could use `std::variant` or `std::any`.

Comment: In C# `object` is not a keyword, it's a *type*. It's the type of the root class that everything inherits from. And since C++ doesn't have such a "root class" it's not possible to do something similar in C++. You might be able to use something like [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), but I would rather recommend that you reconsider your design to be more tailored to the target language (C++).

Comment: @someprogrammerdude you're not just `std::any`one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how would you approach this to be more tailored to C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike C#, C++ does not have a total type hierarchy. There is no base type `int` and  `std::string` share.  In fact `int` doesn't even have a base type, it is a fundamental type (built in) and is not a class type.

This means you have to great lengths to achieve something like the C# code.  If you know that the types will be limited to some set of types then you can use a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).  If you don't have any such limitations then you have to use a [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).  `std::variant` is like/is a tagged union where `std::any` utilizes [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) to store any object inside it.  You can then use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to modify the object stored in the `variant`/`any`.  Since `std::variant` has a known set of types it gives you more ways to access they type stored in it.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to make the design more c++ specific instead? Because of @Someprogrammerdude comment.

Comment: @snzm: That would depend on what the program is supposed to do, which you haven't told us.

Comment: @snzm It really depends on what you are doing.

Comment: My bad. I'm going to read from `std::cin` and store it as tokens to do math calculations. So I need to implement a `TokenStream` class that has the methods `Token get()` and `void putback(Token t)`.

Comment: @snzm if you said that right from the beginning then the answers would be better. In case of parsing a token stream then there's no need to store any types in the variable. This is an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282). Declare your problem instead of stating what you're trying

Comment: @snzm In that case you would do something like [this](http://www.stroustrup.com/dc.c). The code comes from Branje Stroustrup, the creator of C++, in his book "Software - Principles and Practice using C++".

Comment: @phuclv very helpful, amazing.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a lot of casting in there but a void* in C++ represents a pointer to **Anything**. Think of it as a general data store, no length attached to it or anything, just a position.

Depending on what else you need to do it might come in handy.

You can use some `try{}` wrapped casts to see if it is one of your accepted types

Comment: I'm afraid that if I do that, that the `&variables` I pass get deleted or clash somehow.

Comment: @phuclv True! I work mostly in pre-modern so always forget there's a std smart pointer now

Comment: @snzm It's not a big deal if you handle it correctly. But handling it correctly would require some research